# Using superclass type for subclass instance

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, type-conversion

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the usual answers are far from satisfying in my view.

given the following class hierarchy:

```
class SuperClass{}
class SubClass extends SuperClass{}
```

why does people use this pattern to instantiate SubClass:

```
SuperClass instance = new SubClass();
```

instead of this one:

```
SubClass instance = new SubClass();
```

Now, the usual answer I see is that this is in order to send `instance` as an argument to a method that requires an instance of SuperClass like here:

```
void aFunction(SuperClass param){}

//somewhere else in the code...
...
aFunction(instance);
...
```

But I can send an instance of SubClass to aFunction regardless of the type of variable that held it!  meaning the following code will compile and run with no errors (assuming the previously provided definition of aFunction):

```
SubClass instance = new SubClass();
aFunction(instance);
```

In fact, AFAIK variable types are meaningless at runtime. They are used only by the compiler!

Another possible reason to define a variable as SuperClass would be if it had several different subclasses and the variable is supposed to switch it's reference to several of them at runtime, but I for example only saw this happen in class (not super, not sub. just class). Definitly not sufficient to require a general pattern...

Comment: It's because they don't want to know what kind of subclass the instance is. They are interested in context of superclass.

Comment: In other words, it's subjective to what you need ATM, not a best practice. Right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main argument for this type of coding is because of the [Liskov Substituion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that if `X` is a subtype of type `T`, then any instance of `T` should be able to be swapped out with `X`.

The advantage of this is simple. Let's say we've got a program that has a properties file, that looks like this:

```
mode="Run"
```

And your program looks like this:

```
public void Program
{
    public Mode mode;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mode = Config.getMode();
        mode.run();
    }
}
```

So briefly, this program is going to use the config file to define the mode this program is going to boot up in. In the `Config` class, `getMode()` might look like this:

```
public Mode getMode()
{
    String type = getProperty("mode"); // Now equals "Run" in our example.

    switch(type)
    {
       case "Run": return new RunMode();
       case "Halt": return new HaltMode();  
    }
}
```

**Why this wouldn't work otherwise**

Now, because you have a reference of type `Mode`, you can completely change the functionality of your program with simply changing the value of the `mode` property. If you had `public RunMode mode`, you would not be able to use this type of functionality.

**Why this is a good thing**

This pattern has caught on so well because it opens programs up for extensibility. It means that this type of desirable functionality is possible with the smallest amount of changes, should the author desire to implement this kind of functionality. And I mean, come on. You change one word in a config file and completely alter the program flow, without editing a single line of code. That is desirable.

Comment: This is a good answer indeed, but the advantage here depends on this specific design (implementation of boot modes as custom object as apposed to HashMap for example) but I can see how modular/extensible applications can profit of this practice. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Another thing, this (like most other answers here) deals with parameters and not variables. So basically it doesn't answer my question. But I guess the real answer is that local variables doesn't gain a thing from it (unless they are meant to hold the value of a parameter) and that Fields obviously have a deep connection to public methods as in getters and setters so wherever a parameter can gain from being a superclass a field has to be a superclass also to gain.

Comment: To my mind, I think it's more about following these practises, so it *opens* these doors fro you in the future. If you get knee deep into an application, and your boss turns around and goes "I want the program to completely change if I type in a different word here", and you've been following these principles, you've already laid all of the foundation for it.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases it doesn't really matter but is considered good style.
You limit the information provided to users of the reference to what is nessary, i.e. that it is an instance of type `SuperClass`. It doesn't (and shouldn't) matter whether the variable references an object of type `SuperClass` or `SubClass`.

**Update**:

This also is true for local variables that are never used as a parameter etc.
As I said, it often doesn't matter but is considered good style because you *might* later change the variable to hold a parameter or another sub type of the super type. In that case, if you used the sub type first, your further code (in that single scope, e.g. method) *might* accidentially rely on the API of one specific sub type and changing the variable to hold another type might break your code.

I'll expand on Chris' example:

Consider you have the following:

```
RunMode mode = new RunMode();

...
```

You might now rely on the fact that `mode` is a `RunMode`.

However, later you might want to change that line to:

```
RunMode mode = Config.getMode(); //breaks
```

Oops, that doesn't compile. Ok, let's change that.

```
Mode mode = Config.getMode();
```

That line would compile now, but your further code might break, because you accidentially relied to `mode` being an instance of `RunMode`. Note that it might compile but could break at runtime or screw your logic.

Comment: Great answer, but I didn't ask about method signatures. I asked about using the specific design I described in my OP...

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel I also didn't talk about method signatures ;) Within a method there are also users of local variables who don't/shouldn't need to know the exact type.

Comment: You did indeed :) 'Config.getMode()' is not an instantiation, but a static function call. It returns an instance of the type declared in it's signature, hence you talk about signatures. You didn't talk about methods though, my bad. ;)

Comment: Within a method, not knowing the type can only have sense if the value is returned - not if it was instantiated locally. That's why you talked about function calls and not about instantiation. And that is why I made my annoying comment :)

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel If you _only_ talk about instantiation, then yes, you don't need to assign the new instance to a variable of the super type. But your code generally doesn't just involve instantiation and might _change_ later (that was the point of my update), that's why using the super type is considered good style. Btw, you're not really talking about instantiation but about _assignment_ ;)

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel maybe I really don't get it because: 1. with _instantiation_ (`new SubClass()`) there is no way around using the sub type, 2. your examples are about _assignment_ (`SuperClass instance = ...`) - But nevertheless, I cite you: `... require a general pattern... ` -> there is no such requirement, it's just a common convention and a reasonable one, but you don't have to adhere to it.

Answer (score 2):

`SuperClass instance = new SubClass1()`

after some lines, you may do `instance = new SubClass2();`

But if you write, `SubClass1 instance = new SubClass1()`;

after some lines, you can't do `instance = new SubClass2()`

Comment: Read my post carefully, I mentioned this answer and said why it didn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 1):

**It is called polymorphis and it is superclass reference to a subclass object.**

```
In fact, AFAIK variable types are meaningless at runtime. They are used 
only by the compiler!
```

Not sure where you read this from. At compile time compiler only know the class of the reference type(so super class in case of polymorphism as you have stated). At runtime java knows the actual type of Object(.getClass()). At compile time java compiler only checks if the invoked method definition is in the class of reference type. Which method to invoke(function overloading) is determined at runtime based on the actual type of the object.

```
Why polymorphism?
```

Well google to find more but here is an example. You have a common method `draw(Shape s)`. Now shape can be a `Rectangle`, a `Circle` any `CustomShape`. If you dont use Shape reference in `draw()` method you will have to create different methods for each type of(subclasses) of shape.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson about Polymorphism, but if you'd look at the tags I've given you'd see that one of them is "polymorphism". I know about Polymorphism and my argument is that this coding practice I've mentioned has nothing to do with Polymorphism. See my OP (again) if you want to know why I think so...

Comment: I guess you added the last paragraph after I posted my answer or I missed it. Anyways point is it is totally design specific. Now waht happens in real software world is that softwares are not created once. It is cycle of releases and upgrades. You have seen this pattern in a class(no sub,super) probably because it is kind of general precaution(or design convention in one sense) with the assumption that the code will be modified in future and there is a possibility that inheritance may come into picture at a later point of time.

Comment: Also to answer your question **In other words, it's subjective to what you need ATM, not a best practice. Right?**
Yes it is subjective to what you need ATM is your design dictates so(you are very sure that this aspect of code will not be modified in future). But the general convention is to use polymorphic references.

Comment: As you can see, I never edited the OP so you must have missed it. About the real software world, I guess this depends on the kind of apps you create, whether these are desktop apps, mobile apps, server apps, what platform they are built on etc. Perhaps you use this practice all the time, and others may not. I personally asked this question because I've seen this practice a lot here on SO but not at work, and it made me wonder why those who use it do so.

Comment: Also, you took it to method signature also and that was not my question (I do use polymorphic parameters also and even Interface type parameters, but my question was about declaring a variable, not a parameter)

Comment: If it is strictly about declaring variables then yes you are right it is a matter of choice and there is no general pattern as such.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a design point of view, you will have one super class and there can be multiple subclasses where in you want to extend the functionality.

An implementer who will have to write a subclass need only to focus on which methods to override

Comment: Okay, I guess almost everyone here should have seen this answer and skip their own because most of them basically said the same thing. Again, I mentioned this answer in my post and explained why it wasn't good enough for me. Basically, this depends on the goal of your code. If you arn't writing extensible apps this will become unnecessary and heavy. And you did say that "This is from a design point of view" so basically I agree with you. Thanks.